# Force outlook to send all attachments as google drive, s3, or one drive link

Tags: exchange, outlook, file-sharing

I'm trying to find a solution for a client that is constantly sending oversized (20MB+) email attachments via outlook desktop application.  I'm wondering if anyone has had any success finding a way to change the default behavior when adding an attachment to upload the file to a filesharing service (I'm agnostic to which one) and add a link for download inlace of the original file ?

I was thinking about trying to do this myself in code but would rather not reinvent the wheel.

(Outlook 2013 and up connected to rack space hosted exchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn´t specify which "hosted Exchange" you mean, there is a solution with Exchange Online (a hosted Exchange Version). Using Exchange Online (part from the Office 365 branch) you could use Microsoft OneDrive to store such attachments and only include a link.

As starting point Microsoft has a good documentation about that [here](https://blogs.office.com/2014/10/08/introducing-new-way-share-files-outlook-web-app/).

[image]

Comment: I put at the end that it's backspace hosted, exchange.  Is there anyway to leverage this feature without having to go to a 365 subscription ?

Comment: Not sure here but as Microsoft install exchange 2016 in there and exchange online / office 365 Stuff you might rebuild such a setup in an on premises environment.